# Getting and setting interface addresses

Tags: linux, networking, ioctl, netlink

Is there a way to get and set IP address on an interface in family agnostic way?

I have found about getifaddrs. Is there something similar but for setting addresses, or I need to use ioclt?

Here is my case: I need to extend an IPv4 application managing interfaces to support IPv6 addresses also. This application uses ioctl for AF_INET. My question is what would be the best approach for me to do add/delete/status for an interface to support IPv6 also - add
another ioctl layer for IPv6, or mix netlink for IPv6 with ioctl for IPv4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to netlink anyway. The reasons:

1. netlink allows to manage multiple IP addresses on the same interface w/o so called «aliases» etc.
2. ioctl interface is obsoleted already for ages
3. asynchronous status monitoring using netlink is really simple: one should subscribe to a required group on a `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket and then just `poll()` + `recv()`.

The `ifaddrmsg` structure is not family agnostic, one has to specify `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` as a family in the message, + `IFA_ADDRESS` and other NLA size depends on the family. But it can be managed easy at the application level.

For C there is a [libnl](https://github.com/thom311/libnl) library, for Python — [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2).